# How to write unit test redux connected components in next.js app with Jest end Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, next.js

In React Single Page App, we need to separate the logic of `createStore` to another component (usually called `<Root />`) to reuse it in your test file to let `connect` function link with the store

Root.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducers from "reducers";
import { applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxPromise from "redux-promise";

const appliedMiddlewares = applyMiddleware(reduxPromise);

export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
 const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, appliedMiddlewares);
 return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```

And then in your test file, to `mount` or `shallow` your component, your code should look like this:

```
import Root from "Root";

let mounted;

beforeEach(() => {
  mounted = mount(
    <Root>
      <CommentBox />
    </Root>
  );
});
```

But for the case of `Next.JS`, the logic to let redux works with it was implemented in `_app.js` file, with some wrapper components (`<Container>`, `<Component>` ) that I do not know how it works so I could not find the way to separate the `createStore` logic

_app.js

```
import App, { Container } from "next/app";
import React from "react";
import Root from '../Root';
import withReduxStore from "../lib/with-redux-store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";


class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, reduxStore } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withReduxStore(MyApp);
```

Anyone knows it ? Many many thanks for helping me solve this.

Comment: In the end, were you able to solve it? I have a similar issue and I think the store is not being initialized because the initial state is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I'm late adding a response, but this is what I did and worked!

First I imported the custom app:

```
import App from "../_app";

import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { state } from "../../__mocks__/data";

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)(state);
```

Then I mocked the `getInitialProps` from the `_app.js` like:

```
const context = {
  store: mockStore,
  req: {
    headers: {
      cookie: ""
    }
  }
};


const props = await App.getInitialProps({
  ctx: context,
  Component: {
    getInitialProps: jest.fn(() => {
      return Promise.resolve({ ... });
    })
  }
});
```

Then, debugging over `node_modules\next-redux-wrapper\src\index.tsx` I noticed how the `initialState` must be set.

Then I added the following code:

```
delete window.__NEXT_REDUX_STORE__;
const wrapper = shallow(<App {...props} initialState={state}/>);

expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

And run the tests, everything now works as expected.

If there is a cleaner solution please let me know.

I hope It works for you!